# Opening a file inside a subroutine for read/write in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to open a file inside a subroutine to basically substitute some lines in the file. But since, it was not working, I tried a simpler way of printing a line instead of substitute, for debug purposes. Following is the subroutine code.

```
sub replace {

    while (<INPUT_FILE>){

        my $cell = $_[0];
        our $rpl;

        if ($_=~ /^TASK\|VALUE = (.*)/ ) {

            my $task = $1;
            chomp $task;
            $rpl = $cell . '_' . $task . '_bunch_rpl';
            print "000: $rpl\n";

        }
        elsif ($_=~ /^(.*)\|VALUE = (.*)/ ) {

            my $line = $_;
            chomp $line;
            my $ip_var = $1;
            my $ip_val = $2;
            chomp $ip_var;
            chomp $ip_val;
            my $look= $ip_var."|VALUE";
            open(REPLAY_FILE, "+<$rpl")  || die "\ncannot open $rpl\n";
            while (my $rpl_sub = <REPLAY_FILE>) {
                if ($rpl_sub =~ /^$line/) {
                    print "\n 111: $ip_val";
                }       
            }
            close REPLAY_FILE;
        }
        elsif ($_=~ /^\s*$/) {
            print "\n";
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

The code prints the following as of now.

```
000: lfr_task62_bunch_rpl

 111: 2.0.9.0
 111: INLINE
 111: POWER 
000: aaa_task14_bunch_rpl
```

Expected output is:

```
000: lfr_task62_bunch_rpl

 111: 2.0.9.0
 111: INLINE
 111: POWER 
000: aaa_task14_bunch_rpl

 111: 0.45
 111: NO
```

The input sample is:

```
    TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = lfr
    TASK|VALUE = task62
    TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 2.0.9.0
    CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE = INLINE
    JUNK_LINE = JUNK
    JUNK_LINE = JUNK
    FULL_ESD|VALUE = POWER 

    TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = aaa
    TASK|VALUE = task14
    CUSTOM_CELL_DENSITY|VALUE = 0.45
    CUSTOM_CELL_SS|VALUE = NO
```

Can someone tell me the mistake I am doing here?

### UPDATE: Main code below

```
my @cell_names;

open(INPUT_FILE, "<$ip_file")  || die "\n!!!ERROR OPENING INPUT FILE. EXITING SCRIPT!!!\n";

while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
    if ($_=~ /(.*) =\n/ ) {
        $mw -> messageBox(-message=> "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n");
        exit;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /(.*) =\s+\n/ ) {
        $mw -> messageBox(-message=> "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n");
        exit;
    }
    elsif ($_=~ /(.*) = \s+(.*)/ ) {
        $mw -> messageBox(-message=> "\nFormat not correct on line $. of input file. Exiting script\n");
        exit;
    }

    elsif ($_=~ /^TASK_CELL_NAME\|VALUE = (.*)/ ) {

        my $cell_name = $1;
        chomp $cell_name;

        unless(grep( /^$cell_name $/, @cell_names )) {
            push @cell_names, "$cell_name ";
            #$count++;
            #print "\nCELL NAME: $cell_name\n";
            replace($cell_name);
        }
    }
}
close INPUT_FILE;
```

## Update: `lfr_task62_bunch_rpl` before running code:

```
# Select fund
FUND|VALUE = mmi

# Select bank
BANK|VALUE = citi

# Select cell name
TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = lfr

# Select task
TASK|VALUE = task62

# Select task version
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 1.0.9.0

# Select fund type
FULL_ESD|VALUE = MUTUAL

# Select customer premium
CUSTOM_CELL_SS|VALUE = YES

# Select customer brand density
CUSTOM_CELL_DENSITY|VALUE = 0.76

# Select card chip
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE|VALUE = OUTLINE
```

Expected lfr_task62_bunch_rpl after running code:

```
# Select fund
FUND|VALUE = mmi

# Select bank
BANK|VALUE = citi

# Select cell name
TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = lfr

# Select task
TASK|VALUE = task62

# Select task version
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 2.0.9.0

# Select fund type
FULL_ESD|VALUE = POWER

# Select customer premium
CUSTOM_CELL_SS|VALUE = YES

# Select customer brand density
CUSTOM_CELL_DENSITY|VALUE = 0.76

# Select card chip
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE|VALUE = INLINE
```

Comment: How is this subroutine called? What parameters does it expect? Also, we'd need a sample of the other file that gets opened.

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code?

Comment: I didn't have them before. But when I them now, the output is a little different. Its printing the 111 correctly, but doesnt have the value of the $rpl_file.  I have edited it in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I've tidied the indentation of the code a little.

Comment: @Gordon: It's not very helpful if you remove the original text of the question. It means that the answers you've already received no longer make any sense.

Comment: @DaveCross : sorry about that. I thought that would make less data for everyone to process. However, thanks to all the suggestions here, I have managed to get the code working for the most part of it, except the last bit where i am stuck on. So, this is the gist of it. Didn't want to make the question too long for everyone, by having the modificatons I did, pile up on the thread. Will keep your suggestion in mind though, for the next time.

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116963).

Comment: @haukex :Yes I did - thinking these were two different group of programmers and I would get a response from atleast one. Didn't know its such a HUGE deal to ask a question to different bunch of people.

Comment: It's not a "huge" deal, I was just providing links between the two copies. At least over on PerlMonks, crossposting is acceptable for exactly the reason you named, to reach a wider audience, but it's appreciated when the author informs about it, so that if the question already got a good answer somewhere, someone else doesn't waste their time re-answering it; that's all.

Comment: @haukex : sure. thanks. i get your point.

Comment: Crossposting is fine, but please let people know. It's a bit inconsiderate to get an answer in one place but still have people working on it in another place.

Comment: @briandfoy:  I get your point - didn't think about it. Wont happen in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what this code is supposed to do. But I can immediately see a few problems with the logic. Let's step through a few iterations of the loop, using your sample data file.

The first time, the line of data read in is:

```
TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = lf
```

So that matches on your second regex match. You set a few variables and then (because `$ip_var` is equal to "TASK_CELL_NAME") you skip to the else clause and close a filehandle that isn't open.

Next time round, we read:

```
TASK|VALUE = task62
```

That matches your first regex match. The variable `$rpl_file` is set to "XXX_lfr_bunch_rpl" (where 'XXX' is the parameter passed to the subroutine - obviously, I don't know what that is). You print a "000" line with that value and open the file with that name in r/w mode.

Third time round, we get this data:

```
TASK_VERSION|VALUE = 2.0.9.0
```

This matches your second regex and because `$ip_var` isn't equal to "TASK_CELL_NAME" we go into the `if` clause. This reads from your open filehandle and prints a "111" line. But this generates a warning if you have `use warnings` switched on as the line includes the value of `$rpl_file` which is currently defined. It was set the last time around the loop, but because the variable is declared inside the loop, it has now lost its value. We then close the filehandle.

The fourth iteration will be the last one that's really interesting. We get this data:

```
CHIP_PKG_TYPE|VALUE = INLINE
```

This also matches the second regex, so we do a lot the same as the third iteration. But the difference here is that when we try to read from the filehandle, we get a warning because that filehandle is closed. Oh, and then we close it again for good measure :-)

As I said at the start, I can't really work out what we're trying to do here. But I can see that the logic is very strange. You really need to go back to the drawing board and think through your logic again.

**Update:**

With the updated version of your code, I'm still seeing problems.

On the first iteration, the data is:

TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE = lf

So this matches your second regex. That goes into the piece of code that opens the other file and tries to read from it. But it expects to find the filename in `$rpl` and that variable hasn't been given a value yet. So the `open()` fails and the program dies.

Comment: Hmm - let me try and figure this out like you said, maybe my logic is flawed. I will try to amend any flaws I find, and get back to you on the results. Thanks for giving me an insight.

Comment: Yeah, I would strip it right back to basics (using Dave's comments above) and then keep adding functionality until it breaks. Then hopefully you'll have a nice clear sight of where the problem lies

Comment: _Had a review of the code and updated it as seen in the question above now. However, i am stuck with the print of the lines around the second time the regex matches for *TASK_CELL_NAME*_

Comment: @DaveCross : _But then , if that's the case, how is it printing the_  `000: aaa_task14_bunch_rpl`  _if_  `$rpl` _doesn't have a value as yet? Forgive me if i am sounding too naive here, but I am not really a programmer, I am just trying to process some text files, using Perl, to make my job easier. I am not very used to programming, and, as such, a newbie_

Comment: _Have updated the main code also in the question above._

Comment: @Gordon: I'm not getting the output that you are. In my tests, it dies on that line without printing anything. Which, I guess, only proves that my jury-rigging of your code doesn't accurately reflect what you're running. If you could provide us with a minimal complete runnable example that demonstrates the problem, then I expect we could be more help to you.

Comment: @DaveCross : _Based on the input file, I open some other text files and try to replace the lines from the input file into the other text file. The text files I have are named as_  `aaa_task14_bunch_rpl, aaa_task22_bunch_rpl, aaa_task89_bunch_rpl, lfr_task14_bunch_rpl, lfr_task62_bunch_rpl,`  _etc. So, based on the **TASK_CELL_NAME|VALUE** _and_ **TASK|VALUE** _from the input file, my program should open the corresponding correct text files, and replace the other values.Updated a sample of the text file in the question too. Using the print statements as of now to debug _

Comment: Thanks all for your time. Something is wrong, others are getting a different output and I am getting a different one. I will look into this further and update when I get a solution. This thread is also posted on `https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116963`. If there is any resolution , I will keep you guys posted. Thanks again.

Comment: (Clickable version of that link - https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116963)